# How to use a feedback from API

Tags: flutter, dart

so im calling an API with some JSON feedback like so :

```
[{"student_name" : "Raskal", "student_classes" : "XII"}]
```

I call this using this format :

```
Future< StudentInfo > _studentCard() async {
    var data = await MainApi("meKTA", 'getEKTA', '', "getEKTA");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data);
    var jsonParse = jsonData[0];
    final StudentInfo studentinfo = StudentInfo(
      jsonParse['student_name'],
      jsonParse['student_classes'],
    );
    print(data);
    return studentinfo;
  }

class StudentInfo {
  final String student_name;
  final String student_classes;
 
  StudentInfo(
    this. student_name,
    this. student_classes,
  );
}
```

I tried to call the API feedback like this

```
Text(snapshot.data.student_name)
```

but i get an error on the `student_name`
the result i want is that the TEXT shows Raskal

Error I got

```
The property 'student_name' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

on SDK : ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0", Ive got no problem on calling like that, but on sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" ive got that problem

Comment: What error have you got? Please clear your question

Comment: The error is pretty clear, You should check `info_EKTA_Background` null first

Comment: @mikenlanggio Wrong edit sorry, ill edit it again

Comment: Updated my answer, you can check it out

Answer (score 0):

Since SDK 2.12. Flutter using `Sound null safety`. You have to migrate all of your code to run your app correctly. See more: [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Try to check null before passing data into `Text`.
The simplest way you can do it like this one:

`Text(snapshot.data?.student_name ? '')`

Comment: this error shows `The getter 'student_name' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

Comment: Can you parse your code line error? I don't think it error at `Text(snapshot.data?.student_name ? '')`. Maybe you use `data.student_name` other place

Comment: the feedback of the API is a String but i cant call it, but when i turn my SDK low to 2.11.0 there's no error

Comment: Because since SDK 2.12. Flutter using `Sound null safety`. You have to migrate all of your code to run your app correctly. See more: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: i did, this is my new project, thats why i dont know how to call it

Comment: You have to parse the code error. Everyone can help you.